# Font Icon IE 8 issue

Tags: css, fonts

I am using font icons from this excellent site http://fontello.com/ . But on IE I am getting for some of the fonts two small vertical bars . You can see the issue below . Could some one let me know any work around for this ?  Thank You

[image]

You can try this just by downloading these fonts from http://fontello.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the font makers will give you a stylesheet/javascript file titled something like "i.e-fix", and sometimes you are just S.O.L. Font Awesome has some great, **very** compatible font icons.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank You for your answer . Yes I saw font awesome . It is really cool But 1 ) I can not customize and download only the required fonts . I have to download all of them 2) I am looking for two users together icon , some thing like 12th icon in the 2nd image I provided in the question ( Facebook friends notification icon ..)

Comment: Also I see from where I downloaded also provided IE 7 Compatibility code . But some it is not working . Thanks again

Comment: was there a JavaScript file provided, sometimes they have both?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and unfortunately no java script provided

Comment: I am sorry I don't see any errors . Did you get a change to download it and see ?  Thanks again for your response

Comment: unfortunately I dont have access to IE8. Maybe its time to add a "your browser is outdated" alert. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank You for your response . I am going to use image sprout for now . I see there are still there are good number of people using IE8 :(

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate. Or you could use Font Awesome. Not a perfect solution, but a viable one